# Организация таблиц в бд

Tags: mysql

Подскажите как организовать стуктуру таблиц для данного примера.Есть пакеты,для каждого пакета есть опции, которые можно будет менять из админ панели,то есть название иконку и так далее,то же самое можно делать с пакетами,менять иконку цену название.Думал по началу сделать все в одной таблице пакетов,и поля с опциями,но в таком случае не смогу менять название их,а так же добавлять какие то новые.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 5):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Один из способов хранения небольших структур с изменяемым составом свойств - сделать вот так.

Comment: Думал по поводу такого варианта.То есть получается для каждого плана надо перечислить все опции которые он имеет? План->опция одна запись?

Comment: Да. При этом в любой момент можно добавить любую новую опцию, просто расширив таблицу AttributeNames.

Comment: Спасибо за совет!